# Access Hibernate Validator messages

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate-validator, spring-validator

I'm using Hibernate Validator with Spring Boot. I have a variable in a class that I annotated like below.

```
Public class User {

@Pattern(regexp=".+@.+\\..+", message="Wrong email!")
private String userEmail;

}
```

I'm using the validation in a controller.

```
@PostMapping("/users")
public ResponseEntity addUser(@Valid @RequestBody User user, BindingResult result) {

    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        log.info("There are errors in the input");
    }

    ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
        Set<ConstraintViolation<User>> inputErrors = validator.validate(user);

        log.info("Errors: "  + inputErrors.toString());
}
```

Is there an easier why to access the validation messages then through the factory? Something like

```
result.getMessage();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can autowire message source to your controller

```
@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;
```

and get the message

```
messageSource.getMessage(<your key from the error>, null, locale);
```

You ned locale to get properly localized text. You need to iterate the errors to get all messages for all found validation errors.

Comment: Would the key in my case be `userEmail`? Is there a good way of retrieving the locale?